# Get Longest Path between two Nodes - Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, shortest-path, longest-path

I want to get the longest path between two nodes.

I have stations with id's
The stations are connected with oder stations.
Relationships are "Taxi", "BUS", "Boat".

So how do I get the overall longest Path? (or longest shortest Path)
I dont want the longest Path for specific nodes.

I tried multiple queries, but very often I get only "Internal Error..."

This is a cut-out from my graph (here shortest path):
[image]
In my head I think I have to find all shortest paths for all nodes, and then return the longest shortest path.
But I don't get it in a query

Comment: Internal error can occur if the memory usage of that query exceeds the maximum memory permissible. You need to describe more about your problem.

Comment: edited my question,
I thin my main problem is to get a query..
I'm pretty new to neo4j

Comment: What version of neo4j are you using? Which queries have you tried?

Comment: I am running version 3.2.0.
one query i tried is: 
MATCH p=(n)<-[*]-(m)
 RETURN length(p)
 ORDER BY LENGTH(p) DESC
 LIMIT 1

Comment: Have you tried [allShortestPaths](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/match/#all-shortest-paths) ?

Comment: yes I tried also allShortestPath, but i dont know how to get this worked with all nodes. Not only for given Node-id's. Here is my tried query: MATCH (start:Station {id: 1}), (end:Station {id: 191})
MATCH p=allshortestPaths((start)-[*]->(end))
RETURN p
But i want this not only for id 1 and 191

Comment: if you do this on all yours Stations, you will have subgraph of yours Station and theirs relationships no ?
Problem with longest-path is that you can traverse the all graph ... so it's not a good idea.

Comment: And if you simply ommit the ids like: `MATCH (start:Station), (end:Station) MATCH p=allshortestPaths((start)-[*]->(end)) RETURN p`? Probably doing it you are getting a memory error, right? This is because this operation is very expensive to the database... I believe you should think about another strategies instead of calc all the longest paths between all the pair of nodes.

Comment: 1. Since your graph has cycles, the "longest path" between 2 nodes can be infinitely long. You need to specify exactly how to determine the "longest path" (e.g., do you want to avoid revisiting the same node, or revisiting the same relationship, or use some other approach?). 2. neo4j can just as easily traverse a relationship in reverse order. You probably do not need duplicate relationships going in opposite directions.

Comment: there are some helpers, like apoc.expandPathConfig that allow you to specify end conditions, uniqueness, DFS, and depth. Otherwise, I'd write a custom bit of java code with the traversal API.

Comment: Hello I am having this same issue with the code :
MATCH p=(n:ICDNode)-[:ParentOf*]->(m:ICDNode)
WHERE n.ICDCode = 'O14_9' AND m.ICDCode = 'H00_H59'
RETURN p
ORDER BY length(p) DESC
LIMIT 1

Can anyone help?